# Container with different data types: 2 approaches, only one compiles. Why?

Tags: c++, types, containers

I have a question in the hope that someone here might help me understand that issue. I am currently trying to build a code that needs a container with different types. I have found a formulation that works fine but only after having started out with a slightly different formulation that does not compile. And I do not understand why. Can somebody explain to me why version 1 in the following code does not compile whereas version 2 does?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>


struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

class segment
{
public:
    segment() 
    {
        P1.x = 0;
        P1.y = 0;

        P2.x = 0;
        P2.y = 0;
    };
    virtual ~segment() {};

    virtual double get_radius() { return 0; };
    virtual double get_length() { return 0; };
    virtual double get_angle() { return 0; };

    int segment_id = 0;

protected:
    point P1;
    point P2;
};

class Line : public segment
{
public:
    Line() {};
    Line(const point pt1, const point pt2)
    {
        P1.x = pt1.x;
        P1.y = pt1.y;

        P2.x = pt2.x;
        P2.y = pt2.y;

        segment_id = 1;
    };

    ~Line() {};

    double get_length() { return calc_length(); };
    double get_angle() { return calc_angle(); };

private:
    double calc_length()
    {
        // calculate length (here: dummy value)
        return 1;
    }

    double calc_angle()
    {
        // calculate angle (here: dummy value)
        return 0.5;
    }

    double length = 0;
    double angle = 0;
}
;

class circle : public segment
{
public:
    circle()
    {
        center.x = 0;
        center.y = 0;
    };
    circle(const double r, const point c)
    {
        radius = r;
        center.x = c.x;
        center.y = c.y;

        segment_id = 2;
    };

    ~circle() {};

    double get_radius() { return radius; };
    point get_center() { return center; };
    double get_length() { return 3.14 * radius; }; //returns circumference

private:
    double radius = 0;
    point center;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int nbr = 5;
    point start;
    start.x = 1;
    start.y = 2;

    point end;
    end.x = 3;
    end.y = 4;

    point c;
    c.x = 0;
    c.y = 0;

    double r = 9;

    circle* myCircle = new circle(r, c);
    Line* myLine = new Line(start, end);
    
    //VERSION 1: Does not compile. I get an exception in <memory> line 1762 when trying to delete _Ptr
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v1;

    v1.emplace_back(myCircle);

    v1.emplace_back(myCircle);

    std::cout << v1[0]->get_radius() << std::endl;

    v1.emplace_back(myLine);

    std::cout << v1[1]->segment_id << std::endl;


    //VERSION 2: Compiles
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v2;

    v2.emplace_back(new circle(r, c));

    std::cout << v2[0]->get_radius() << std::endl;

    v2.emplace_back(new Line(start, end));

    std::cout << v2[1]->segment_id << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Version1 should **compile**, but leads to UB with double free.

Comment: You should avoid `new` completely, use `std::make_unique`.

Comment: `unique_ptr` should have the unique ownership of the pointer, but you are creating two `unique_ptr` elements in your version1 vector that point to the same place. It makes no sense to use raw pointers in that case so it's much better to go with version2 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very likely this:

```
v1.emplace_back(myCircle);

v1.emplace_back(myCircle);
```

This will create two different `std::unique_ptr<segment>>` objects, both using the exact same pointer to the exact same object. This breaks the *unique* part of the `std::unique_ptr`.

When the first element is destructed the second become invalid, and attempting to destruct the second will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You need to create two different objects that are truly unique:

```
v1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<circle>(r, c));
v1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<circle>(r, c));
```

---

If you want only a single `circle` object and that the vector elements should share this object, then `std::shared_ptr` might be a good idea. ***But*** you still can't create it like you do now, instead you must copy from the first element to the second.

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<segment>> v1;

v1.emplace_back(std::make_shared<circle>(r, c));
v1.emplace_back(v1[0]);  // Create a shared copy of the first circle element
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Some programmer dude. This explanation helps a lot. I wonder if shared_ptr may be another way... have to learn about that one first tho.

Comment: @ManyQuestions: The `shared_ptr` idea has two things to consider. Will it work (yes), and will it work like you intended (perhaps). You should realize that after changing to `shared_ptr<Circle>`, you'd still have one circle, but it appears twice in `v1`. With the suggestion in this answer, you'd make two circles.

Comment: Thanks, MSalters. I still have to learn a lot in C++ 8O